# The best way to initialize multiple Objects of the one Class in C#

Tags: c#

I have an app where people can enter details into a console, all the details are stored as an Object, the problem is I don't know how many are needed so initialization needs to happen dynamically. I have decided to use a List is this the right thing to use? If not some pointers in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List is fine,  assuming your object is called "InputData" do something like the following

```
public List<InputData> InputList = new List<InputData>();

public void Builder()
{    
   string input = Console.Readline();
   InputData id = new InputData(input);
   InputList.Add(id);
}
```

then you can iterate through that data at a later point with a foreach

```
foreach(InputData i in InputList)
{
    i.dosomething;
}
```

Not sure if this is what your wanting to do,  let me know fi you have a more specific query

Answer (score 0):

I think you are look for Something like the Following:

```
Class Foo
{
   //class definition here
}
main()
{
int count=10;//Can be dynamic
Foo fooObject= new Foo();
List<Foo> fooList=Enumerable.Repeat(fooObject, count).ToList();
}
```